# How to make multiple bootstrap buttons share a certain width in a row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

As based on my example below, how can I make `<div id="full">` take the full width of the parent and have the 3 buttons inside share this width and have the same sizes with gaps between them?

[image]?

Is there a Bootstrap class that can do that?

```html
<script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js integrity=undefined crossorigin=anonymous></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css integrity=undefined crossorigin=anonymous>

<div class="d-grid gap1">
  <div id="full">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">shared width button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">shared width button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">shared width button</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">full width button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [Bootstrap flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)

Comment: Agreed with @Rory use Bootstrap flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) to achieve this.

Add the `d-flex` class to the parent container of the buttons, then `flex-fill` to each button. You can also use the [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) to add gutters between the buttons and the following content.

```html
<script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js integrity=undefined crossorigin=anonymous></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css integrity=undefined crossorigin=anonymous>
<div class="d-grid gap1">
  <div id="full" class="d-flex mb-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success flex-fill me-1">shared width button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success flex-fill me-1">shared width button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success flex-fill">shared width button</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">full width button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom class for #full:

```
.custom-flex { 
    display:flex; 
    gap:30px;                  /* custom gap */
}
.custom-flex > * { 
   flex:1;                    /* add full width for children */
}
```